# Does the human body need alcohol?

Tags: alcohol

Does the human body need alcohol intake? I would like to question the common wide-spread belief that that the healthiest amount of etanol intake is 0 mg/year.

Comment: [very much related](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/is-alcohol-beneficial-in-small-amounts)

Comment: Hello Jani and welcome. Please provide a reputable source for the claim.

Comment: As an aside the human body obviously doesn't *need* alcohol. many people never drink alcohol at all, and lead perfectly healthy lives.

Comment: Alcohol is a dangerous liquid. It’s like a poison to human body and can cause a lot of damage. So in conclusion, no, it does not need such thing. The body require healthy food and drinks.